# Individual s3 bucket for each user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, storage

I have a Laravel application, I want to have a secure storage system for my registered users.

1. How should I plan for it, should I create a new bucket for each user, or create folders for each user inside one bucket
2. How can I restrict users not to access each others folders?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely go with one bucket for all and then separate it with folders. Buckets is more to separate apps for interaction with each other in my opinion.

I would create a prefix and always use that, you could secure they can't interact with each other files, if the code uses the same functions.

```
public function saveFile($user, $fileName, $file) {
    Storage::put($user->getS3Prefix() . $fileName, $file )
}

public function getFile() {
    return Storage::get($user->getS3Prefix() . $fileName)
}
```

Now on your user model, have a prefix generation, in theory that could be the user id.

```
class User {
    public function getS3Prefix() {
        return "/{$this->id}/";
    }
}
```

This is a simple straight forward solution and i do not feel like you need to overthink this.

There is a clever solution, S3 config has a root option, that indicates which folder there should be the root.

So in a service provider, you could actually do something like this.

```
if ($user = Auth::user()) {
    config(['storage.disks.s3.root' => "/{$user->id}/"]);
}
```

I think this is a little to flaky solution and hard to control whenever there is not a user in context for example in commands or jobs. But think it is appropriate as another alternative solution.